# ¿Puede un proceso hijo pasar por el estado zombie y el de huérfano?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Me gustaría saber si un proceso hijo creado con fork() puede pasar de ser zombie a huérfano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Un proceso entra en estado zombie porque ha muerto, pero su padre aún está vivo (y no ha recogido apropiadamente la señal `SIGCHLD` que el hijo le envió al terminar).

Tan pronto como muera el padre, el zombie, en lugar de quedar huérfano, pasará casi inmediatamente a ser "adoptado" por el proceso de PID 1 (el proceso `init`), el cual consumirá su señal `SIGCHLD`, con lo que el zombie dejará de ser zombie y desaparecerá. En el intervalo entre que su padre muere y es adoptado por `init` seguirá en estado zombie.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias